# Cannot show complete graph on y-axis in Python Matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am new to python and I am trying to plot in a graph in python, but the plot on y-axis is not completely visible. I need to increase the y-limits from -1000 to 7. But, matplotlib cuts the graph above 0 in case I specify such high ylimits. And if I specify smaller limits like -10 to 10, it doesn't show the complete graph on negative y-axis. I tried to save figure using tight layout but that also did not help.

I am using Python 3.6.3 and Jupyter notebook.

Below are the graphs for plt.ylim(-10, 5.5) and plt.ylim(-1000, 5.5), respectively.

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Is there anyway to increase the y-limits to very high so that the whole graph is visible?

Here is my code snippet for the graph:

```
plt.plot(tVec,psp,'b',linewidth=2,label='PSP')
plt.ylim(-10, 5.5)
plt.xlabel("Time (ms)")
plt.ylabel("PSP")
plt.legend()
plt.savefig("test.png",bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()
```

Comment: The whole graph *is* visible if you expand the limit, it is just hard to see. You could try to raise the upper bound to something like 100 or use a log scale.

Comment: Can you explain this part please - " You could try to raise the upper bound to something like 100 or use a log scale". Not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: For the former, you could try `plt.ylim(-1000, 100)`

Comment: This worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see the y axis as a logarithmic one ([Wikipedia Logarithmic Scale](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_scale?wprov=sfla1)) you could set it up with `plt.yscale('log')`